# Find the polar coordinates from given Cartesian coordinates

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the polar coordinates, $0 \leq \theta < 2 \pi$ and $r \ge 0$ of the following Cartesian points:
$$
(4 \sqrt{2},4 \sqrt{2})
$$
The way I would approach this is using 
$$
r^2=x^2+y^2
$$
so:
$$
r^2=x^2+y^2=(4\sqrt{2})^2
$$
If I am not mistaken $(4 \sqrt{2})^2 = 32$ but my homework is telling me $r^2 = 64$

What am I missing?

Comment: You forgot to add $x^2$ and $y^2$. What you have set equal to $r^2$ is just $x^2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x=4\sqrt2,$ and $y=4\sqrt2$, so $$r^2=x^2+y^2=(4\sqrt2)^2+(4\sqrt2)^2=32+32=64$$
You only counted one of those, instead of both.

Comment: ahh! I was doing "find the cartesian coordinate" problems I completely brain farted and misread the question. Was assuming $r=4\sqrt{2}$

Comment: @Anon haha, yes that happens from time to time :)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong in your logic, but you just had a minor glitch:

Instead of being:
$$
r^2=x^2+y^2=(4\sqrt{2})^2
$$

it should be:

$$
r^2=x^2+y^2=2\times (4\sqrt{2})^2
$$